# I am not able to use CSS order property

Tags: html, css, media-queries, flexbox

I am trying to run this code according to which the order of the boxes should change for screen size larger than 700px.
But it does not happen as such, and there is no visible change.
What is it that I am doing wrong?

http://jsbin.com/xabegeziro/edit?html,css,output

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.header {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}
.blue-box {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}
.red-box {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}
.dark-green-box {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
}
.purple-box {
  background-color: purple;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
}
.orange-box {
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}
.light-blue-box {
  background-color: #00d0ff;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}
@media sceen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .header {
    order: 1;
  }
  .orange-box {
    order: 2;
  }
  .purple-box {
    order: 3;
  }
  .red-box {
    order: 4;
  }
  .dark-green-box {
    order: 5;
  }
  .light-blue-box {
    order: 6;
  }
  .blue-box {
    order: 7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="blue-box"></div>
  <div class="red-box"></div>
  <div class="orange-box"></div>
  <div class="purple-box"></div>
  <div class="dark-green-box"></div>
  <div class="light-blue-box"></div>
</div>
```

My media query is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px){
  .header { order: 1; }
  .orange-box { order: 2; }
  .purple-box { order: 3; }
  .red-box { order: 4; }
  .dark-green-box{ order: 5; }
  .light-blue-box{ order: 6; }
  .blue-box{ order: 7; }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your media query: it's "screen", not "sceen".

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. — Most of your code is only available on JSBin.

Comment: @Abhishek you wasted several minutes to post this question on SO but you couldn't take a minute to check your code? Get Rekt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1.Ensure you have added viewport metatag in your page:
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

2.And There's a typo in your media query.
  Replace sceen with screen.
```